# Select object between date - sqlite

Tags: php, json, sqlite, date, object

How can I select data between two dates (now and 6 days after)?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
$date = date('Y/m/d', time());
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE Date between '$date' and '$date + 6 days'";
```

This is the script php and this is my table on phpMyAdmin

```
Database my_sitoscuolaprovablog
Table structure for table events
Column  Type    Null    Default
id  int(11) No  
title   varchar(100)    No  
date    date    No  
description varchar(2000)   No  
image   varchar(200)    No  
hour    time    No  
address varchar(250)    No  

Dumping data for table events
1   Ciao    2014-06-02  Bellissima festa per tutti  http://sitoscg.altervista.org/events/schoolisover.jpg   08:20:56    Via Momo Lolo
2   Miao    2014-06-09  Fluo    http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-pA0UrBxfNPw/UFi-s5GRcnI/AAAAAAAARYI/lo0f4tX15Dc/s1600/yes.png 10:04:05    lolo
```

But when I click on my php file the web return

```
null
```

Why?

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `Date` column?

Comment: what is your problem now

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has very powerful [date handling functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) that allow you to do this query in pure SQL (without the PHP date() function). So the only line you need is this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE Date between date('now') and date('now', '+6 days')";
```

Note that by default SQLite will use UTC for calculation.  If your server operating system  is set to the timezone you want ('Europe/Rome') you can use the 'localtime' modifier.